# Сравнение элементов массива указателей типа базового класса

Tags: c++, сортировка, указатели, сравнение, полиморфизм

Есть два класса: `Point`, `Pixel`. `Pixel` производный от `Point`. 
Есть масив указателей `Point*`, в котором хранятся указатели на объекты типа `Point` и `Pixel`. 
Нужно отсортировать массив таким образом:

- При сравнении `Point` и `Point` -- сравнение результатов `p1.dist()` и `p2.dist()`
- При сравнении `Point` и `Pixel` -- сравнение результатов `p1.dist()` и `p2.dist()`
- При сравнении `Pixel` и `Point` -- сравнение результатов `p1.dist()` и `p2.dist()`
- При сравнении `Pixel` и `Pixel` -- сравнение результатов `p1.dist()` и `p2.dist()`. Если они одинаковые то сравнить цвет (`string`) двух пикселей.

**Мое решение:**

В классах *Pixel* и *Point* есть перегруженные виртуальные функции less(методы класса), которые параметром принимают соответственно *const Pixel& и const Point&*

**Проблема:** 
Разыменование указателя на *Point* возвращает не динамический тип, а *const Point&*, потому при вызове:

```
Point* p1=new Point;
Point* p2=new Pixel;
return *p1<*p2;
```

Для операнда *p1* вызывается функция *less* из класса соответствующего динамическом типу *p1* благодаря механизму полиморфизма. Но независимо от динамического типа *p2*, всегда вызывается перегруженная функция *bool less(const Point&)*, вместо *bool less(const Pixel&)*

**Немного разъясню:**

```
*p1<*p2; //Point::less(const Point&) вместо Point::less(const Pixel&)
*p2<*p1; //Pixel::less(const Point&)
*p1<*p1; //Point::less(const Point&)
*p2<*p2; //Pixel::less(const Point&) вместо Pixel::less(const Pixel&)
```

Comment: `dist()` - виртуальная? Если нет, ее можно сделать виртуальной? Просто если она виртуальная, сравнивайте результат ее вызова через указатель на `Point` и не мучьтесь...

Comment: @Harry Это не позволяет сделать 4 пункт условия

Comment: Откровенно говоря, не понял, почему.

Comment: @Harry метод dist()-расстояние от начала координат. А если оно одинаковое, то для пикселей нужно сравнить еще и цвет. Не буду же я в методе для получение расстояния сравнивать цвета -- семантически неправильно.

Comment: А почему нет? Любое сравнение <=> основано на понятии расстояния, а расстояние -- это всего лишь некоторая скалярная функция от двух точек векторного пространства. Чтобы такая функция была расстоянием всего-то нужно, чтобы она была неотрицательна и симметрична относительно аргументов. Так что не выдумывайте себе ограничений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну попробуйте такой компаратор:

```
class Point
{
public:
    virtual int dist() const;
};

class Pixel: public Point
{
public:
    virtual int dist() const;
    string color() const;
};


bool less(const Point* p1, const Point* p2)
{
    if (p1->dist() < p2->dist()) return true;
    if (p1->dist() > p2->dist()) return false;

    const Pixel* x1 = dynamic_cast<const Pixel*>(p1);
    const Pixel* x2 = dynamic_cast<const Pixel*>(p2);

    if (!x1 || !x2) return false;

    return x1->color() < x2->color();

}
```